# Using awk to compare array string to string from awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I would like to make an array in bash that uses awk to compare a word to a string held in an array
so far i have:

```
     name=( "name1" "name2" "name3" )
     num=0
     awk -F, '$2 == name[0] { num += $1 }; END { print num }'  ~Me/stuff/home.txt
```

for some reason this doesnt work but if i replace name[0] with "name1" it works fine. home.txt looks like

```
     81920,name1
     84985,name2
     11000,name3
     71111,name1
     etc...
```

Any help would be appreciated thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` doesn't have access to your shell variables, especially when you use single quotes for your `awk` code. To go with the code  you have, you could do

```
    awk -F, '$2 == "'"${name[0]}"'" { num += $1 }; END { print num }'  ~Me/stuff/home.txt
```

Above I have written dbl-quote single-quote dbl-quote surrounding the `${name[0]}` variable. This allows the shell to interpolate the value from the shell environment into the body of the awk code. Note that to compare the value (using `==`) with `$2`, it is best that the value is seen as a string inside of awk. So the comparsion made after the substitution of the shell variable is `$2 == "name" { ...`

You would find it instructive to run this code preceded by the shell debug/trace flags, `set -vx`. Turn off the trace/debug with `set +vx` after the code of interest.

**But** better to pass that value in with

```
awk  -F, -v name="${name[0]}" '$2 == name { num += $1 }; END { print num }'  ~Me/stuff/home.txt
```

**output**

```
153031
```

IHTH

Comment: I've answered your direct Q, and I'm very glad my answer helped you. But, be aware that `awk` could easily process all of the list you have mentioned in 1 process rather than calling `awk` 3 times. Maybe your problem is more complex than what you have shown, and it makes sense to call `awk` individually for each name, but if not, consider posting a revised question that describes your sources of data, the list to process (and describe it), and required output from those. Including some code will show that you have attempted to solve your problem (as you have done here) and get you help faster.

Comment: Thanks to @glennjackman for correcting the first set of code. I'll change the related comment to match. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4):

To pass a bash array to awk, you'll have to stringify the array and split it inside awk.

```
bash_array=( "some data" "with spaces" "but no commas" )
awk -v ary_data="$(IFS=,; echo "${bash_array[*]}")" '
    BEGIN {num_elements = split(ary_data, awk_array, /,/)}
    # ... do stuff with awk_array ... 
}'
```